# Can I simplify a Spring comparator?

Tags: java, spring

I found this source code in `org.springframework.core.OrderComparator`

```
private int doCompare(Object o1, Object o2, OrderSourceProvider sourceProvider) {
    boolean p1 = (o1 instanceof PriorityOrdered);
    boolean p2 = (o2 instanceof PriorityOrdered);
    if (p1 && !p2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (p2 && !p1) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Direct evaluation instead of Integer.compareTo to avoid unnecessary object creation.
    int i1 = getOrder(o1, sourceProvider);
    int i2 = getOrder(o2, sourceProvider);
    return (i1 < i2) ? -1 : (i1 > i2) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I think, `return (i1 < i2) ? -1 : (i1 > i2) ? 1 : 0;` could be simplified as:

```
return i1 - i2;
```

Am I right?

Version:
Spring 4.3.11.
Java 1.8.

Comment: Why on earth would you think about simplifying Spring core's code?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got the answer: `i1 - i2` could be overflow.

```
public void testCompare() {
    int i1 = -2000000000;
    int i2 = 2000000000;
    System.out.println(i1 - i2);
}
```

Output is: 294967296

Seems a little stupid. But, whatever...

Answer (score -4):

You are wrong.

A comparator should return zero or one or minus one. The result of i1 minus i2 could be something other than zero or 1.

It could be ten, minus six any valid int.

The javadoc of getOrder make no mention of its return values.

the code of getOrder

```
Object[] sources = ObjectUtils.toObjectArray(orderSource);
                    for (Object source : sources) {
                        order = findOrder(source);
                        if (order != null) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong.  Nowhere in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) does it say that it has to be zero or one.

Comment: @JoeC what ? getOrder javadoc doesn't mention valid values

Comment: No, the point is not valid. The contract is clear and makes no reference to the number `1` (whether negative or positive).

Comment: Of `Comparable.compareTo()` and `Comparator.compare()`. You know the thing being discussed in the quesiton.

Comment: "A comparator should return zero or one or minus one." [citation needed]